# Show menu bar on multiple screens without separate spaces

Tags: menu-bar, spaces

I have two screens. I want:

- Windows to be able to span multiple screens
- A menu bar on both screens

Is that too much to ask? There is an option that affects both of these: "Displays have separate Spaces". With it on you get two menu bars but windows cannot span multiple screens. With it off you they can but you only get one menu bar. Is there a solution to this madness?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

The menu either belongs to your primary screen, or if you have 'Displays have separate Spaces' on, then to the one currently active.

If you have different Spaces on different screens, there is no logic to control any window being able to span the two. What would happen if you changed Space on only one of them?

There is no third option, as far as I'm aware, even with 3rd party software.

Comment: This is the right answer, but to elaborate on a point briefly made in the answer, when the displays have separate Spaces, you don’t get ‘two menu bars’, you get one on the active display and one semi-transparent picture of the same menu bar displayed at the top of the other. There appears to be some fixed limitation on having more than one menu bar, or spanning that menu bar across displays.

Comment: Ah, thanks @grg - I have limited experience with separate Spaces. if you want to jump in & add that into the answer, feel free. You might just be able to word it more accurately than I could, for a definitive answer. [also feel free to delete both comments afterwards]

Comment: Your answer was perfect! I don’t know if what I said was worthy of being in your answer since I’m basically nitpicking on something based on precise wording in the question that was probably not intended anyway… maybe chat deserves my narration instead!

Comment: @grg - no worries then, we can leave it as a comment. :)